# Emulating ReadAsync

Tags: .net, asynchronous, f#

In .Net 4.5 there exists a method on the Stream class which read asynchronously from a stream while monitoring the cancellation token.

```
ReadAsync : 
       buffer:byte[] * 
       offset:int * 
       count:int * 
       cancellationToken:CancellationToken -> Task<int>
```

If another thread should first trigger the cancellation token then closes the stream, then is it guaranteed that the reading thread will be cancelled before ReadAsync throws an exception?

Can I somehow achieve this guarantee using the .Net 4.0 framework and F# asynchronous workflows without ReadAsync(which has no overload which accepts a cancellation token to be monitored)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This particular overload is basically useless unless you're chaining multiple tasks together – `cancellationToken` is only checked upon entry to the `ReadAsync` method call, and not while the underlying `Stream.BeginRead` call is executing.

Code dumped from ILSpy:

```cs
public virtual Task<int> ReadAsync(byte[] buffer,
                                   int offset,
                                   int count,
                                   CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        return this.BeginEndReadAsync(buffer, offset, count);
    return Task.FromCancellation<int>(cancellationToken);
}
```

As you can see, `cancellationToken` is not forwarded into the `BeginEndReadAsync` call, and `BeginEndReadAsync` is merely implemented in terms of `Stream.BeginRead`:

```cs
private Task<int> BeginEndReadAsync(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
    return TaskFactory<int>.FromAsyncTrim<Stream, Stream.ReadWriteParameters>(
        this,
        new Stream.ReadWriteParameters
        {
            Buffer = buffer,
            Offset = offset,
            Count = count
        },
        (Stream stream, Stream.ReadWriteParameters args, AsyncCallback callback, object state) =>
            stream.BeginRead(args.Buffer, args.Offset, args.Count, callback, state),
        (Stream stream, IAsyncResult asyncResult) =>
            stream.EndRead(asyncResult)
    );
}
```

At this point, the only guarantees you have are those made by the derived stream type, which vary from type to type.

<sup>Note that this is based on the current .Net 4.5 bits, and the implementation is of course subject to change in the future.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can check [`Task.IsCanceled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.iscanceled.aspx) before running the task with `Result`/`RunSynchronously`.

Here's some example code:

```ml
use stream = new MemoryStream(Array.init 1000 (fun i -> byte (i % int Byte.MaxValue)))
use waitHandle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset)
use cts = new CancellationTokenSource()
let thread = Thread(fun () -> 
  Thread.Sleep(1000)
  let buf = Array.zeroCreate 100
  let task = stream.ReadAsync(buf, 0, buf.Length, cts.Token)
  if not task.IsCanceled then task.RunSynchronously()
  waitHandle.Set() |> ignore)
thread.Start()
cts.Cancel()
waitHandle.WaitOne() |> ignore
```

But once `ReadAsync` begins, it *will* throw an `AggregateException` stating the task has been canceled.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you have to both use a mutex to protect the stream and use the cancellation token to check the thread for pending cancellation. There is not asynchronous primitive on `Stream` that handles this for you.