# Convert BeginRead loop into ReadAsync and cancel on demand

Tags: c#, asynchronous, filestream

I trying to build two applications that will communicate over RDP with each other.
I have basic communication, but I would like to optimize code and remove all exceptions.

On server I'm opening FileStream and when I send something from client I'm reading it using `BeginRead`:

```
public void Connect()
{
    mHandle = Native.WTSVirtualChannelOpen(IntPtr.Zero, -1, CHANNEL_NAME);
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        IntPtr tempPointer = IntPtr.Zero;
        uint pointerLen = 0;
        if (Native.WTSVirtualChannelQuery(mHandle, WtsVirtualClass.WTSVirtualFileHandle, out tempPointer, ref pointerLen))
        {
            IntPtr realPointer = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(tempPointer);
            Native.WTSFreeMemory(tempPointer);
            var fileHandle = new SafeFileHandle(realPointer, false);
            fileStream = new FileStream(fileHandle, FileAccess.ReadWrite, 0x640, true);
            var os = new ObjectState();
            os.RDPStream = fileStream;
            fileStream.BeginRead(os.Buffer, 0, 8, CallBack, os);
        }
    });
}
```

and my Callback:

```
private void CallBack(IAsyncResult iar)
{
    if (iar.IsCompleted || iar.CompletedSynchronously)
    {
        var os = iar.AsyncState as ObjectState;
        int readed = 0;
        try
        {
            readed = os.RDPStream.EndRead(iar);
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        if (readed != 0)
        {
            switch (os.State)
            {
                case FileDownloadStatus.Length:
                    os.Length = BitConverter.ToInt32(os.Buffer, 0);
                    os.State = FileDownloadStatus.Body;
                    os.RDPStream.BeginRead(os.Buffer, 0, os.Length, CallBack, os);
                    break;
                case FileDownloadStatus.Body:
                    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(os.Buffer, 0, readed);
                    Debug.WriteLine(message);
                    var newos = new ObjectState {RDPStream = os.RDPStream};
                    os.RDPStream.BeginRead(newos.Buffer, 0, 8, CallBack, newos);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and needed items:

```
enum FileDownloadStatus
{
    Length,
    Body,
}

class ObjectState
{
    public int Length = 0;
    public FileDownloadStatus State = FileDownloadStatus.Length;
    public byte[] Buffer = new byte[0x640];
    public FileStream RDPStream = null;
}
```

Unfortunately when I try to close my application I get exception `System.OperationCanceledException`.

I would like to convert this into ReadAsync because then I could use CancelationToken, but then I must upgrade to .NET 4.5.

I found [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608728/emulating-readasync) question about CancelationToken, but it's written in F# and I need C#.

So my question is:
How can I stop BeginRead or transform this code into .NET 4.5 and use ReadAsync?

Comment: Did you try using Thread instead of Task?

Comment: @Vajura I'll try that right away!

Comment: @Vajura same result with Thread :(

Answer (score 1):

Converting to async/await:

Replace `fileStream.BeginRead(os.Buffer, 0, 8, CallBack, os);` with:

```
    Task<int> task = fileStream.ReadAsync(os.Buffer, 0, 8, cancelToken);

    try
    {
        await task;
        await CallBack(os, task);
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        // TODO: unpack task exception and display correctly
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
```

Note that I assume you have a new `cancelToken` variable containing your `CancelationToken` object. I suppose you might store this in your `ObjectState` object, so that it's readily available where you'll want to call `ReadAsync()`.

Change the first part of your `CallBack()` method (before the `if (readed != 0)` statement) to this:

```
    private async Task CallBack(ObjectState os, Task<int> task)
    {
        if (task.Status != TaskStatus.Canceled)
        {
            int readed = task.Result;
```

I.e. replace all of the code before the `if (readed != 0)` statement with the above, changing the method declaration as above.

Apply similar changes to the code inside the `CallBack()` method, where you also call `BeginRead()`. I.e. use `ReadAsync`, use `await` with the returned `Task<int>`, then pass the `Task<int>` to the callback when the `await` completes, calling it with `await` as well. (You should be able to have just the one try/catch block in the `Connect()` method...exceptions occurring in the continuations should propagate back to that try/catch block).

Note that in addition to the change to the `CallBack()` method declaration, you will need to change the `void Connect()` method declaration so that it's `async Task Connect()`. Note also that this will force callers to themselves become `async` methods and use `await` when calling (and so on, up the call chain until you get to a UI event handler, which can be `async` and use `await`, while legitimately being a `void` method), or to deal with the returned `Task` directly (not recommended, since that generally means negating the benefit of the async/await idiom).

If you keep using the `BeginRead()` method instead, as far as I can recall the only way to cancel that is to close the `FileStream` object (which will cause the operation to complete with an `ObjectDisposedException`).

Finally note: I'm not familiar enough with the RDP I/O to comment on your use of the byte-count result for the async reads. But in other contexts, it would be a really bad idea to assume you have successfully read as many bytes as you originally asked for. Typically, you have to keep looping, reading data until you have as many bytes as you need.

Comment: If I try to use Your code inside `Task.Factory.StartNew()` I get error that await can be used only with methods with async. Could You please extend Your code example? I will be grateful.

Comment: Can you clarify why you were using `Task.Factory.StartNew()` in the first place? Is there a significant delay associated with any of the calls in that block of code? My first thought is to just get rid of it. But if you still asynchronous execution of some of that code (e.g. the call to `WTSVirtualChannelQuery()` is slow), you can run just that in a `Task` and `await` it, just as you'd `await` the call to `ReadAsync()`. If you can clarify the goal here, I'll edit my answer to be more suitable.